# Why AJAX does not change field's value?

Tags: forms, ajax

I wrote simple code:

```
function rah_cc_generate_form($form,$form_state){
    $form=array();

    $form['gen']=array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#name' =>t('generate gift card code'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => false,
//        '#weight' => 5,

    );
    $form['gen']['code']=array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('gift code'),
            //'#default_value' => '',
            '#prefix' => '<div id="gc-code">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#size' => variable_get('rah_gc_code_size', 8),
            '#maxlength' => 20,
            //'#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['gen']['price']=array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('price'),
            '#default_value' => 10000,
            '#size' => 10,
            '#maxlength' => 20,
            '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['gen']['random']=array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('generate'),
    '#description' => t("if you want generate random use this plz"),
    //'#weight' => 1,
    //'#submit' => array('rah_cc_generate_random'), // If no javascript action.
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'rah_cc_generate_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'gc-code',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
   );


    $form['gen']['save']=array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' =>t('save'),
         );

    return $form;


}
function rah_cc_generate_ajax(&$form,&$form_state){

    $form['gen']['code']['#value']=33;
  return $form['gen']['code'];

}
```

but it doesn't work: textfield is not replaced by the one that has value 33.

There is no JS error and AJAX request returns HTTP code 200.

Comment: You just [chameleoned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478) your question. That's pretty much the end of my effort here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Your AJAX callback should return a form element. Now it returns plain `33`.
2. All changes should be made inside form building function, in your case `rah_cc_generate_form`. Simply add condition to test `$form_state['triggering_element']` and perform action if it was your AJAX trigger. Do not alter things in AJAX handler, it's not what it is for. I know it's counter-intuitive, but that's the way it is.
3. Changing default value once there is some user input will have no effect. Maybe you should try to change appropriate entry in `$form_state['input']`? But that depends on your intentions.

Comment: thanks molot, the problem was in another place, I have some mistyping in question, it was old version

Comment: This answer was valid for [first revision of this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/101374/1). I will not update it, as I refuse to support [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478).

Comment: sorry molot, I want delete question, my mistake was in another place and not relate to form api. thanks for you attention  dear molot